# Why "using namespace std;" gives different result when dealing with doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, double, std

Today, I was trying to answer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124627/c-error-in-login-identify-a-valid-triangle-with-greater-greater-then-0-all) (regarding checking whether a triangle can be constructed), when I encountered a weird result.

With the test of `15.15 35.77 129.07`, this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const double e = 0.000001;

void f(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (abs(180 - (a+b+c)) > e) {cout << "test"; }
}

int main()
{
    double a,b,c; cin >> a >> b >> c;
    f(a,b,c);
}
```

prints `test` as normal, while this:

```
#include <iostream>
const double e = 0.000001;

void f(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (abs(180 - (a+b+c)) > e) {std::cout << "test"; }
}

int main()
{
    double a,b,c; std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    f(a,b,c);
}
```

does not. The only difference is the `using namespace std;` line (and when I added `using namespace std;` to the second piece of code, as expected, it ran normally).

I've read a lot of post regarding `using namespace std;` over time:

- [Using Namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077566/using-namespace-std)
- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- ...

but it seems that the only things `using namespace std;` do is cut some corners, in exchange of occasional conflicts of name of classes/variables/namespaces (the point that is brought up most when debating about whether to use it).

I did find 1 relevant post : [Why does g++ (4.6 and 4.7) promote the result of this division to a double? Can I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721295/why-does-g-4-6-and-4-7-promote-the-result-of-this-division-to-a-double-can) , but I didn't find anymore info elsewhere.

So what I'm I missing here?

-- Some machine info:

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- Code::Blocks 20.03
- gcc/g++ 6.3.0

Comment: FWIW, your code has undefined behavior.  `abs` does not live in `<iostream>`, and you havent included the header you want `abs` from.  Most likely you are pulling in different functions, or maybe even a macro vs a function.

Comment: Have some warnings for case (2) - live - https://godbolt.org/z/W4c81ssb7 this should explain

Comment: Second example wouldn't compile on my machine, missing `abs`.  I added `#include <cmath>` and changed `abs` to `std::abs`.  It printed `test`.

Comment: @Eljay You've got a better implementation that OP's. Ideally, I'd want my C++ headers not to polute the global namespace as OP's does. But there's sadly no requirements on C++ implementation to.

Comment: @YSC • I use my own non-polluting headers.  They work great for compiling.  Not so good for linking (...like, not at all).  Helps me find mistakes in implied header dependencies.

Comment: @Eljay nice! A github repo to share with us maybe?

Comment: @YSC • Not ready for primetime yet because they're incomplete (about 50% of the standard C++ headers).  Haven't shared on github.  I call my project *deader files* because they're just stubs without much in the way of implementation.  `constexpr` is messing me up, too, since they're not compile time evaluation friendly.  They're only for C++14, because that's what I'm currently working in (not by choice, I'd rather move to C++17 for now, and C++20 ASAP... but my project is stuck in C++14).

Comment: It is often a good idea to avoid user input in example code. Given the accepted answer, I take it you did not try replacing `double a,b,c; std::cin >> a >> b >> c;` with `double a = 15.15, b = 35.77, c = 129.07;`? Not only would that have made it easier to reproduce your result, but also it would eliminate one spot where `namespace std` comes into play.

Comment: @JaMiT yes, I'll take notice of that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *do* have a name conflict: [`int abs(int)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) versus [`double std::abs(double)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs).

With `using namespace std;`, `abs(180 - (a+b+c))` finds both and `std::abs` is a better match.

Without `using namespace std;`, `abs(180 - (a+b+c))` only finds the former and a conversion to `int` is necessary, hence the observed behaviour.

What you really want is:

```
#include <iostream>
const double e = 0.000001;

void f(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (std::abs(180 - (a+b+c)) > e) {std::cout << "test"; }
}

int main()
{
    double a,b,c; std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    f(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `std::fabs` to explicitly document your intention NOT to use the integer version.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So the post I found did have some right on this case. I was really confused for a while now.